# Spherical geometry as an example of non euclidean geometry

Tags: math-history, spherical-geometry

I have recently been learning some hyperbolic geometry and the professor briefly mentioned spherical geometry. From a modern, naive point of view, it seems quite easy to show that spherical geometry is an example of non euclidean geometry.

Clearly, this is not true since it took over a 1000 years to do this. Is the apparent difference in difficulty due to my modern viewpoint or were there technical difficulties like with hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: All of the difficulties are conceptual; the hard part is recognizing that spherical geometry deserves to be called geometry at all. Obviously arcs aren't straight lines, in the same way that obviously negative numbers aren't numbers (e.g. if you think that numbers measure lengths, obviously negative lengths are meaningless).

Answer (score 3):

The key modern insight here is the distinction between axioms and models, in other words between syntax and semantics. Euclidean axioms were once thought to characterize a unique *space* whatever that may be. The idea that truth of a proposition may be relative to a model is a revolutionary idea that we take for granted today.

Answer (score 2):

To an ancient geometer (or one from the 18th century), spherical geometry would seem to violate Euclid's second postulate, which says that any finite straight line can be extended indefinitely. 
It is also a problem that two great arcs intersect in *two* points, rather than one, which would be natural for straight lines. Thus, it would seem as spherical geometry differ from Euclidean geometry in more than the validity of the parallel postulate.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely delayed response. You say that "...it would seem as though...". Don't the points you mention actually prove that spherical geometry differs significantly from euclidean geometry. I do know that you can take the projective space and identify antipodal points. But the other restriction seems too severe for any such modification.

Comment: @Paprika To identify antipodal points is OK today, but would in ancient times violate the definition of a point ("that which has no part"). I agree that spherical and Euclidean geometry differ significantly, and that to bridge these differences you have to rework your definitions and foundations, which goes a long way of explaining why it took so long time.

Comment: What I meant to ask was how one would go about bridging the differences.I understand how to bridge one of them, but the other one seems much harder(extending a straight line indefinitely). Pointing me to a reference would be absolutely fine too.